# Size of labels in a TableLayoutPanel

Tags: vb.net, tablelayoutpanel

I've been stuck in this for two hours now. I googled for the answer a lot, and still can't figure out what's wrong with my program.

I have a TableLayoutPanel1 in a form2. This is the code in which I create labels, a list and then add all of those labels to the TableLayOutPanel1:

```
Public Class Form2

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lbl0, lbl1, lbl11, lbl2, lbl22, lbl3, lbl33, lbl4, lbl44, lbl5, lbl55, lbl6, lbl66, lbl7, lbl77 As New Label
    lbl0.Text = "ACCESORIOS"
    lbl0.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("MS Reference Sans Serif", 15.75, FontStyle.Bold)
    lbl0.Location = New Point(110, 12)
    lbl0.AutoSize = True
    Me.Controls.Add(lbl0)
    lbl1.Text = "Té 180°"
    lbl11.Text = Te180
    lbl2.Text = "Té 90° Empalme - Codo Triple"
    If Global1 <> 0 Then
        lbl22.Text = 0
    Else
        lbl22.Text = Global2 - 1
    End If
    lbl3.Text = "Soporte 90° T/T"
    lbl33.Text = SoporteTT90
    lbl4.Text = "Base para tubo de 1 1/2 - 3 agujeros"
    lbl44.Text = Int(lbl11.Text) + Int(lbl22.Text) + (lbl33.Text)
    lbl5.Text = "Base para tubo de 1 1/2 - 1 agujero"
    lbl55.Text = 2
    lbl6.Text = "Tapas para base de tubo de 1 1/2"
    lbl66.Text = lbl44.Text
    lbl7.Text = "Tornillos y Tarugos 5 x 50 y N°8 Ladrillo Hueco"
    lbl7.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("MS Reference Sans Serif", 15.75, FontStyle.Bold)
    lbl77.Text = (Int(lbl44.Text) + Int(lbl55.Text)) * 3
    Dim labellist As New List(Of Label)()
    labellist.Add(lbl1)
    labellist.Add(lbl2)
    labellist.Add(lbl3)
    labellist.Add(lbl4)
    labellist.Add(lbl5)
    labellist.Add(lbl6)
    labellist.Add(lbl7)
    labellist.Add(lbl11)
    labellist.Add(lbl22)
    labellist.Add(lbl33)
    labellist.Add(lbl44)
    labellist.Add(lbl55)
    labellist.Add(lbl66)
    labellist.Add(lbl77)
    Dim h = 0
    For i = 0 To 1
        For j = 0 To 6
            Dim etiqueta As New Label
            etiqueta.Text = labellist(h).Text
            TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(etiqueta, i, j)
            h = h + 1
        Next
    Next
End Sub


End Class
```

The problem is that the the full label doesn't appear in the table.[enter image description here][1]

I have tried Autosizing the labels, the tablelayout. Nothing works. It's like there's an invisible line that doesn't let the text of the label get past a line in the table. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

The layout in form2. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uRpr.png)

What happens when I make the font in the TLP 5pts. The whole label appears in two lines. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i118g.png)

Comment: I dont know what I am supposed to see in that image - you might have changed the label back color to blue or red to illustrate, but it could be they are not Docked or the margin/padding of the TLP

Comment: The image shows that the texts of the labels is not complete. If you see the code, many names are much longer.

Comment: Fine but I cant tell if that is because of the TLP width or something else - everything is all grey everywhere, no way to tell where the labels start and end.  Make sure to use DockFill with them.

Comment: I tried this with one of the labels: lbl4.Dock = DockStyle.Fill. I still don't get to see the whole text of the label. The width of the TLP is given in form2.vb (design form). I will edit the main text and add more pictures.

Comment: Ummm `lbl4` is never added to the TLP.  You create all those lables with special properties and add them to a list.  Then you loop thru the list and **create a new new of labels** which only has the text pf the special ones in the list.  You also dont need that long list of labels at the top - one temp var is all you need.  Change the color of lbl4 or 7 and you wont see that color on the form.  The new label you create in the loop will still have the default values.  Then at the end of the method, all the lables in the list go away without being disposed.

Comment: Oh, please kill me. Of course lbl4 is never added! I was so dumb! Thank you so much! It's fixed now! Thank you thank you thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mainly, you create all those labels, store them in a list. Then all you use them for is to set the text on another **new** label you create to add to the controls collection.

Here is a shorter, simpler way to do all that with no extra list, and just one scratch label variable for the TLP set:

```
Dim texts = {"Te 180", "Te 90 - blah blah blah", "Soprte 90 T/T",
             "Torillas y salsa", "Torillas y salsa y guacamole"}

Dim lbl As Label
For n As Int32 = 0 To texts.Length - 1
    lbl = New Label
    lbl.Text = texts(n)
    ' more important than autozise, probably:
    lbl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    ' debug: to see the border for tweaking
    lbl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
    ' add the one you created to the controls collection
    tlp1.Controls.Add(lbl, 0, n)
Next
```

Comment: Will do. Thanks! This webpage is amazing. People are very helpful and quick to answer.